# Bring task to front on widget click

Tags: android, widget, task, move, back

I sent a task (activity) to back with:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

but I need bring it to front by setOnClickPendingIntent in widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start the main (root) activity of your application like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

If the activity is already running in a task, this will just bring that task to the foreground (without creating any new instances of the activity). If the activity is not already running, then this will start a new task with that activity at the root.

Comment: also i perform it by add (android:launchMode="singleInstance") in manifest.

Comment: single instance is usually a bad idea. This is only for HOME-screen replacements. You probably don't need that. Android won't create another instance of the activity if it is already running as the root of an existing task. Unless you are developing a HOME-screen, using singleInstance will probably make more trouble than benefits.

Comment: thanks very much, but how i can start main activity like that? am i put that in OnCreate?

Comment: No, you want to put this in the PendingIntent that you pass to `setOnClickPendingIntent()`. Like this: `Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

In my situation,FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is useless.It will recreate the activity though the activity exists in the task.

But singletask launchmode works well.