# Widget click gives back last activity

Tags: android, android-widget

When I click on my application widget, instead of going back to the last activity I left open (when going into the home screen), Android restarts my application from scratch.

Is there a way to make that click behave exactly like my app icon, or like the "recent apps manager"?

Here is how I implemented the widget:

```
public class WidgetLauncher extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            Intent active = new Intent(context, COPD_Main.class);
            active.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, active, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.launch_support);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.launch_support_launcher, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I am aware there are several questions around like:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369785/bring-task-to-front-on-widget-click)

but it did not fix my problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the Intent flag you are using. Try to use:

```
active.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

isntead of NEW_TASK.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP):

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at
>   the top of the history stack.